# Laravel update form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hash, bcrypt

Hello i'm using laravel and i'm using a specific method for users, seller and another type of user.

So if i'm updating a form of users ( them contain : pseudo, password, if the seller have paid ad another field ) the password was updated if the field is null, and i don't want this and i can't show the password because laravel use bcrypt for hash password and we can only verify if the hash is the same as a password entered as a plain text.

My problem is really specific, i have serch solution but no on have the same problem. Any solution ?

```
 public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $inputs = $request->all();
    dd($inputs);
    $seller = Seller::find($id);
    $seller->pseudo = $inputs['pseudo'];
    $seller->password = Hash::make($inputs['password']);
    $seller->token_related_product = $inputs['token_related_product'];
    $seller->save();
    return view('backend.home');
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem? You don't want the password to update when the model gets updated?

Comment: Hello @Dan Exactly. I  want if the field is not empty bu if is empty i don't want the password null

Comment: Then just remove the `$seller->password` assignment from your method.

Comment: I know this but i told in my post is a specific problem of bcrypt but if any seller want to change i need this field, but yeah it's a solution but not the best, if you prefer is my last solution if i can't do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to set a new passwort if the `password` field is filled, just compare the value of the field to an empty string. If it's not empty, hash the password and save it to the database, otherwise skip this step.

```php
public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $inputs = $request->all();

    $seller = Seller::find($id);
    $seller->pseudo = $inputs['pseudo'];

    if ($request->filled('password')) {
        $seller->password = Hash::make($inputs['password']);
    }

    $seller->token_related_product = $inputs['token_related_product'];
    $seller->save();

    return view('backend.home');
}
```

Comment: this solution set me the password on null ;) but it's a good idea .

Comment: I have leave $seller->password, and i have create a route for reset them password by an admin