# Why does Laravel say that my "update" method is not a support route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am getting this error when I try to use `update` method from my routes.

```
The UPDATE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE.
```

I am building my project using Laravel and have defined `update` by route in `web.php`

```
Route::get('/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'show']);
Route::delete('/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'destroy']);
Route::post('/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'update']);
```

And my update function in `PostController.php` should just ddd.

```
public function UPDATE(Post $post)
    {
        ddd(request(),$post);
    }
```

and as far as I have seen so long as I have `@csrf` and `method("UPDATE")` everything should be good. This is on my `posts.show.blade.php`

```
<form method="POST" action="/{{$post->slug}}">
    @csrf
    @method("UPDATE")
```

I'm new to Laravel and MVC; where have I gone wrong or what am I missing? On the page where this is failing I have two modal forms, one to update/edit and one to delete. The `delete` method works just fine but `update` fails with the same setup.

To also be clear, these forms are on `/{{$post->slug}}` could the issue be that I am trying to route to `/{{$post->slug}}/{{$post->slug}}` with the form `action` so that then throws off the route?

Comment: Because you declared the route with post method. BTW typically is used PUT or PATCH for updates. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: This `Route::post('/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'update']);` can not work what ever you put in form. Second route above in order will never execute since first one covers that case. 
Also, as @porloscerrosΨ says method is not update but PUT or PATCH depending what you need to do.
To keep with framework standard, third route should be named `store` instead `create`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel update form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904612/laravel-update-form)

Answer (score 2):

As a user already stated, you have to use the `Route::xxxx` you choose, so your HTML should be like:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/{{$post->slug}}">
    @csrf
```

BUT, you have 2 equal routes (string) but pointing to the different controller's methods:

```php
Route::post('/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'update']);
```

The convention/standard here is to:

| Verb | URI | Action | Route Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GET | /posts | index | posts.index |
| GET | /posts/create | create | posts.create |
| POST | /posts | store | posts.store |
| GET | /posts/{post} | show | posts.show |
| GET | /posts/{post}/edit | edit | posts.edit |
| PUT/PATCH | /posts/{post} | update | posts.update |
| DELETE | /posts/{post} | destroy | posts.destroy |

So, you should have:

```php
Route::get('/posts/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('/posts/create', [PostController::class, 'create']);
Route::put('/posts/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/posts/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'destroy']);
```

If you have the routes above, then you have to:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/posts/{{$post->slug}}">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
```

Read [`Actions Handled By Resource Controller`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) for more information.

More info about [`@method`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#method-field) so you don't confuse what it means.

Comment: My hero! Thank you so much for the detailed answer.

Comment: No worries, just remember to always look at the documentation as this is explained, so you don't waste time and get even more confused with other answers, the documentation correctly explains everything, just be his friend ;)

Comment: @brutalnessities if it worked, remember to mark this answer as correct, please

Comment: I didn't have enough rep at the the time but got ya now! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Update your "update" route into being either a PUT or PATCH request that way it's able to distinguish between your two "POST" routes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  In this form method allow only patch method for update the record 


  <form method="POST" action="/posts/{{$post->slug}}">
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
```

Comment: Please explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: You have to add just "" @method('PATCH') "" on your form method

Comment: Then add this information to your answer (not as a comment) and explain why it didn't work without it. That way people resting your answer will get a better understanding of what went wrong and it will make it useful. Welcome to SO! :)

Comment: If you want to update, [edit] instead of commenting.